# How to create an array of sorted indexes of another array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

**I am trying to get an ordered array of index from another array in typescript.**

Let me give examples: consider a function that receives an array of any size and returns another array with the ordered indexes of the Input:

- ex1: Input=(5.3, 2.4, 4.5, 6.2) > Output=(1,2,0,3).
- ex2: Input=(10, 11, 5, 34, 3, 7, 17) > Output=(4,2,5,0,1,6,3).

I can't use `array.sort()` as will change the original array.

I'm stuck, as I have very litle experience whit JS and TS (rusty Delphi programmer).

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice()` to make a copy you can sort without mutating original, then `map()` to create an array of each sorted element's index in the original array.

```js
const data = [5.3, 2.4, 4.5, 6.2],
      data2 = [10, 11, 5, 34, 3, 7, 17];

const sortedIndex = (arr) => {
  return arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b).map(n => arr.indexOf(n))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedIndex(data)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedIndex(data2)));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just copy the array then sort the copy?

```js
var array0 = [4,2,5,7,1.6];
var array1 = [];
for(var i=0;i<array0.length;i++){
  array1.push(array0[i]);
}
array1.sort();
//array0 = [4,2,5,6,1.6]
//array1 = [1.6,2,4,5,6]
```

Comment: This does not make a copy. Try running this yourself. The variables are both references to same array

Comment: Only if values are less than 10. Default for sort is to convert to string and 11 would come before 2

Comment: Thanks. i think in that case i would get the input array sorted, but not the indexes from the input array sorted into a new array! for this ex.of the array0 I would like to get: output = (4,1,0,2,3)! The array i am using is only numbers!

Comment: My bad, I thought they just wanted to use the `.sort()` method and not have it modify the original array, just misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 0):

Only need two lines of code to do this:

```
var unsortedArray = [6, 4, 9, 1, 5];
var sortedArray = unsortedArray.slice().sort();

console.log(sortedArray);      // [1, 4, 5, 6, 9]
console.log(unsortedArray);    // [6, 4, 9, 1, 5]
```